# Assembly: Get position of LSB and MSB

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have an assignment to find the position of the least significant and most significant bits in a number, using NASM assembly. However, I'm running into two problems with even getting what I have to compile:

1. Dividing a number by 2 is not working (`div 2` outputs an `invalid operand` error)
2. I'm running out of registers to use!

Here's what I have right now:

```
%include "along32.inc"

section .data
msg1    db      'Enter a hexadecimal number: ', 0
msg2    db      'LSB set: ' , 0
msg3    db      'MSB set: ', 0
msg4    db      'Total bits set: ', 0


section .text

global main

main:
    mov     edx,    msg1
    call    WriteString
    call    ReadHex     ; eax contains hex number
    mov     edx,    eax ; edx contains hex number

    mov     si,    0   ; si will contain lsb posiiton
    mov     r9w,    0   ; r9w will contain msb position
    mov     bh,     0   ; bh will contain number of bits set
    mov     bl,     1   ; bl will store if the msb is set
    mov     cx,     32  ; loop through every power of two
    mov     eax,    2147483647 ; eax contains 2^31 - 1

bitchecker:
    mov     ebp,    edx ; ebp contains number
    and     ebp,    eax ; ebp contains eax & ebp
    jz      loopend
    inc     bh
    mov     si,    cx ; put value of cx into si
    cmp     bl,     0  ; if msb is already set, jump to loop end
    je      loopend

    mov     r9w,    cx ; put value of cx into r9w
    dec     bl

loopend:
    xor     edx,    edx
    div     2
    loop    bitchecker

continue:
    mov     edx,    msg2
    call    WriteString

    mov     eax,    si ; write lsb
    call    WriteInt

    call    Crlf

    mov     edx,    msg3
    call    WriteString

    mov     eax,    r9w ; write msb
    call    WriteInt

    call    Crlf

    mov     edx,    msg4
    call    WriteString 

    xor     eax,    eax
    mov     ax,    bh ; write total bits set
    call    WriteInt

    jmp end

end:

    call    Crlf

    mov     eax,    1
    int     0x80
```

I don't even know if the logic works first of all, but that isn't my issue right now. It's just that it's really hard to work with all of these registers going on, it gets confusing. How would I avoid these problems?

Edit:

Final solution:

```
%include "along32.inc"

section .data
msg1    db      'Enter a hexadecimal number: ', 0
msg2    db      'LSB set: ' , 0
msg3    db      'MSB set: ', 0
msg4    db      'Total bits set: ', 0

section .text

global main

main:
    mov     edx,    msg1
    call    WriteString
    call    ReadHex     ; eax contains hex number

    mov     ecx,    0  ; ecx contains loop variable
    mov     ebx,    32  ; ebx contains lsb
    mov     ebp,    0   ; ebp contains msb
    mov     esi,    0   ; esi contains how many bits set
    jmp     algo

algo:
    shr     eax,    1
    jnc     not_set
    mov     ebp,    ecx
    inc     esi
    cmp     ecx,    ebx
    jg      not_set
    mov     ebx,    ecx

    ; decrement and check loop condition
not_set:
    inc     ecx
    cmp     ecx,    32
    je      end

    jmp     algo


end:
    mov     edx,    msg2
    call    WriteString

    mov     eax,    ebx
    call    WriteInt

    call    Crlf

    mov     edx,    msg3
    call    WriteString

    mov     eax,    ebp
    call    WriteInt

    call Crlf

    mov     edx,    msg4
    call    WriteString

    mov     eax,    esi
    call    WriteInt

    call    Crlf

    mov     eax,    1
    int     0x80
```

Comment: `div 2` is invalid as any instruction set reference will tell you. The extra funny thing is, people normally use shifts instead of `div 2` and you even want a shift not division so why not just use a shift? By the way, it can be conveniently written using 4 registers. I also assume you are not allowed to use `bsf/bsr` :)

Comment: How would I use a shift?
Well I have no idea how to accomplish this with 4 registers, that seems impossible. @Jester

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `div 2` which is invalid, you could use `shr eax, 1`.

A trivial algorithm is:

```
lsb = 32;
for(i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    if (x & 1)
    {
        if (i < lsb) lsb = i;
        msb = i;
    }
    x >>= 1;
}
```

This only needs 4 registers (`x`, `i`, `lsb` and `msb`).

Comment: How would I loop from 0 to 32? I only know how to loop from 32 to 0.

Comment: Apparently you do know how to use `cmp` and conditional jumps so what's the problem counting up?

Comment: I didn't realize I could use cmp with a value, sorry. Thanks! @Jester

Comment: Also note the shift automatically gives you the lsb into the carry flag so you don't even need to do `x & 1`. You can also count down if you like, then use a left shift and swap the logic for msb/lsb.

Comment: What do you mean? @Jester

Comment: `shr eax, 1` will place the least significant bit into the carry flag so you can just do `jc/jnc`.

Comment: How would I execute the code in the if statement but also execute the code outside of it? What I have now is `shr eax, 1` then I decrement the counter variable, compare it to 32, and jump to the end of the program if it's equal. Then I jump back to the loop. How would I put the if condition in there, with a `jc`? @Jester

Comment: `shr eax, 1; jnc not_set; ... do the stuff with lsb/msb ... ; not_set: decrement and loop`

Comment: Edited my answer in the OP. It might be working? Either way, thanks for the help! @Jester

Comment: For counting up you might want to start from zero and use `inc` not `dec` ;)

Comment: You're right, sorry. That worked. I'm stupid @Jester